# SmartGWT - Display date in yyyy/MM/dd format

Tags: date, smartgwt

I want to have the possibility to display a date with the possibility to enter the date manually.
For this I've uset the attribute `useTextField` set to `true` like:

```
setAttribute("useTextField", true);
```

Now I want the format of date to be yyyy/MM/dd.

I've tryed with

```
setAttribute("displayFormat ", "TOJAPANSHORTDATE");
setAttribute("inputFormat ", "YMD");
```

but nothing happen.

I need to use attributes.
What attribute should I use? And with what value?

Please, need help.
Thanks you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
.setDisplayFormat(DateDisplayFormat.TOJAPANSHORTDATE);
```

Comment: I've managed to solve this with   `date.setAttribute("useTextField", true); 
  date.setAttribute("inputFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd");
  date.setAttribute("displayFormat", "toJapanShortDate");` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009896/smartgwt-dateitem-usetextfield-true-how-to-make-text-entry-field-uneditable

Comment: The date chooser won't show the date on the text field but Today's date.
For example, enter 30/05/2009 on the text field, go to another field, then come back on click on the date chooser and the selected day will be Today's date instead on June 30th, 2009.

How can this be solved?  Thank you!

Comment: I've removed `date.setAttribute("inputFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd");` and works fine. Actually `date.setAttribute("displayFormat", "toJapanShortDate");` give the format of the date. "TOJAPANSHORTDATE Short date in format YYYY/MM/DD. Example: 2005/11/4" from [here](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/types/DateDisplayFormat.html)