# SmartGwt DateItem useTextField=true - how to make text entry field UNeditable

Tags: gwt, date, smartgwt

Since I can't figure out how to solve my problem presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948142/date-browsers-problem-if-manually-changed-and-focus-on-it-did-not-save) I'm thinking for the moment at a temporary solution.

I have a smartgwt `DateItem` widget:

```
DateItem date = new DateItem("Adate");
date.setWidth(120);
date.setWrapTitle(false);
date.setAttribute("useTextField", true); 
date.setAttribute("inputFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd");
date.setAttribute("displayFormat", "toJapanShortDate");
```

Because the attribute `useTextField` is set to `true` we can see the text entry field. How can I make this text entry field to be uneditable. 
Actually I want to have only the possibility to choose the date from calendar and not to change it manually.

**Resolved** - the issue exposed above - thanks to @RAS user.

```
TextItem textItem = new TextItem();
textItem.setAttribute("readOnly", true);
date.setAttribute("textFieldProperties", textItem);
```

[Related link](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=13762)

But I have now another issue (**resolved** - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747288/smartgwt-display-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-format)):
The date chooser won't show the date on the text field but Today's date.
For example, enter 30/05/2009 on the text field, go to another field, then come back on click on the date chooser and the selected day will be Today's date instead on June 30th, 2009. Which is the reason for this? Can this be solved?

**Also let's say I let to the user to opportunity to manually modify the date - can I put some **validators** on it?** (still need an ideea on this)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date.setEnforceDate(true);
```

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/DateItem.html#setEnforceDate%28java.lang.Boolean%29

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of different validators. Depending on the context it must be possible to validate cardinality, relation to other data items, datatype(not only date time values) and relations to other external records.